# ion tabs not displaying

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i tried to put my ion-tabs in the bottom but it´s not shown. Can anyone explain me why  ?

HomePage is:

```
<ion-content padding>

<div id="HomePage">
<ion-item id="profilePictureBox">
<img src="{{user?.profilePicture}}" id="profilePicture">
<h2 id="username">{{user?.name}}</h2>
</ion-item>

<notifications></notifications>

<upcoming-events></upcoming-events>

</div>
</ion-content>

<nav-footer></nav-footer>
```

And my ion-tabs are in component nav-footer:

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="bottom" [selectedIndex]="0">
<ion-tab tabIcon="home-outline" tabTitle="Home" [root]="HomePage">
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="search" tabTitle="test" [root]="SearchEventsPage">
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab>
</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And it is the default css, i changed nothing

[No Tabs in bottom but i can find the tab-component in dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4idt3.png)

Comment: Move <nav-footer> in <ion-content> or else enclose it in <ion-footer>

Comment: i tried it, not works

Comment: can you please share a screenshot ?

Comment: What do you mean? check out this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-otnztv

Comment: @Prasheel i uploaded a screenshot

Comment: @Vega exactly like this

Comment: i got it! but thanks